# Private NAT gateway in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I have a need to connect instances in GCP to an on-premise network through a NAT gateway but apparently this isn't supported by Cloud NAT. Would be happy to hear some suggestions on how this requirement can be implemented.

To give a bit more context:
There will be a cloud interconnect set up however there is a requirement to not have to negotiate IP ranges between on-prem and GCP hence the requirement for the NAT.

Essentially, I need something that achieves the same effect as AWS' private NAT gateway (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

Comment: Can you explain more your use case and your constraint? Do you need to translate your addresses not to have overlapping?

Comment: Why do you want to use a NAT Gateway? Edit your question to show the addressing scheme for the VPC and your on-prem network and who connects to whom. Depending on your architect on-prem you already are using a NAT gateway, so NAT <-> NAT will not work without a lot of fiddling with addresses and ports. In most cases use the correct solution - site-to-site VPN.

Comment: 1/2) If you are using Cloud Interconnect, you do not need NAT Gateway. You can only use NAT Gateway with Cloud Interconnect if you are routing ALL traffic (default route) across the interconnect. Another issue is that Cloud Interconnect already knows the addressing range of your VPC. Your concept of hiding or not configuring addressing won't work.

Comment: 2/2) One idea, which I have not validated, is to use two peered VPCs. VPC A is connected to Cloud Interconnect. VPC B is only peered to VPC A. Build a VM instance set up as a NAT gateway in VPC A. Setup the default route for VPC B to send all traffic over VPC peering to the VM NAT router. The VM NAT Router default route is Cloud Interconnect.

Comment: @JohnHanley (2) is exactly what is currently planned except I'd really prefer to use a managed service rather than roll my own NAT. But it's looking unavoidable at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud NAT service is not intended to allow communication between on-premises network and GCP resources, it just handles the inbound and outbound Address Translations in GCP, as stated in the following document [1].

What you are looking for, is to implement Cloud VPN, which is in fact a GCP service designed to allow communication between on-premises networks and GCP resources, here you can find a complete documentation on how it works and the different modes that can be implemented [2].

Now, for the part about the NAT gateway; if your device cannot create IPsec VPNs, then you would need to add a device acting as a VPN gateway in between first. In that case, you would end up with an architecture like this:

[image]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview

[2] https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview

Comment: Based upon the very limited information in the question, this is the proper answer and recommended solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. To further elaborate, there will be a cloud interconnect set up however there is a requirement to not have to negotiate IP ranges between on-prem and GCP hence the requirement for the NAT.

Comment: @kwong - Your requirement of not negotiating IP ranges not is possible. Cloud Interconnect must know the addressing of both sides, otherwise, traffic will not be routed.